# How to check if the translation is checked by community using googletrans module in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to translate some words using `googletrans` Python module. It translates the words, but I need to check if the translation checked by Google Translate Community. How can I do it?
I've tried to use this code, but the confidence attribute value is always 1.0, though the first phrase is checked by community, and the second one is not:

```
from googletrans import Translator


translator = Translator()  # initialize the Translator
# translate two phrases from English to Ukrainian
translation1 = translator.translate("to be", "uk")
translation2 = translator.translate("I'm fond of programming", "uk")
# print the result and if it is already checked by community
print(translation1.text, translation1.extra_data["confidence"])
print(translation2.text, translation2.extra_data["confidence"])

# It prints:
# бути 1.0
# Я захоплююся програмуванням 1.0
```

[image: Checked by community]

[image: Unchecked by community]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% sure, but it appears there is a flag in "translation" array in the extra data that represents the community checked status.

```
from googletrans import Translator


translator = Translator()  # initialize the Translator
# translate two phrases from English to Ukrainian
translation1 = translator.translate("to be", "uk")
translation2 = translator.translate("I'm fond of programming", "uk")
# print the result and if it is already checked by community
print(translation1.text, translation1.extra_data["translation"][0][4])
print(translation2.text, translation2.extra_data["translation"][0][4])

# Output
# бути 1
# Я захоплююся програмуванням 0
```